How do I search through a table in excel and find 1 cell from a line?
I am trying to scan through a material stock database and find a line that corresponds to the line that is being input.
The spreadsheet is set up as pictured:

The aim is to match the thickness, grade and finish of the new line to another line with the same thickness, grade & finish, & size X=3000 & Y=1500, and return the "10x5 sheet price" for that line.
I have partially got this to work using SUMIFS:
=SUMIFS('10x5 sht price','Thk",B(new line),'Length',3000,'Width',1500,'Grade',C(new line),'Finish',D(New line))
where 'thk' is column B.
but this will obviously sum the prices if there are multiple lines with the same data.
Is there a function which would work better? =IFS doesn't seem to work how I thought it would. I apologise for my ignorance on this!

XLOOKUP(1, (lookup_array1 = lookup_value1) * (lookup_array2 = lookup_value2) * (…), return_array)
